# Cómo numerar en orden cada línea escrita dentro de un fichero en C? Codeblocks

Tags: c, string

Estoy escribiendo un log muy simple en donde cada vez que se ejecuta el programa se agrega en un txt (fechas.txt) la fecha y hora en que se ejecutó dicho programa incluyendo saltos de línea para diferenciar cada ejecución:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fichero;
    char fecha[30]={'\0'},nombre[]="fechas.txt";
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    strftime(fecha, sizeof(fecha)-1, "%d/%m/%Y\t%H:%M hrs", t);

    strcat(fecha,"\n\n\n");
    fichero = fopen(nombre, "a+");
    fputs(fecha, fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
    return 0;
}
```

> Ejemplo de salida:

```
09/07/2020  23:46 hrs


10/07/2020  01:56 hrs


10/07/2020  03:01 hrs


10/07/2020  04:56 hrs


10/07/2020  06:27 hrs


10/07/2020  07:41 hrs


10/07/2020  16:38 hrs


10/07/2020  20:40 hrs


11/07/2020  06:53 hrs
```

Me gustaría entender cómo podría numerar cada ejecución de forma ascendente teniendo en cuenta que el programa debe seguir el orden de numeración sin importar la hora o fecha en que sea ejecutado, por ejemplo:

```
09/07/2020  23:46 hrs   1


10/07/2020  01:56 hrs   2


10/07/2020  03:01 hrs   3


10/07/2020  04:56 hrs   4


10/07/2020  06:27 hrs   5


10/07/2020  07:41 hrs   6


10/07/2020  16:38 hrs   7


10/07/2020  20:40 hrs   8


11/07/2020  06:53 hrs   9
```

Hice un intento usando un archivo log.txt como una especie de contador mediante un `switch` para dar referencia al programa del orden de numeración.

La intención es que en log.txt se escriba únicamente un `char numero` al crear el fichero, y en ejecuciones posteriores leer el caracter contenido en log.txt y reescribirlo por el número consiguiente, teniendo en cuenta que al llegar a la ejecución 8 el contador en log.txt se reinicie a 1 automáticamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fichero;
    char fecha[30]={'\0'}, numero='\0';
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    strftime(fecha, sizeof(fecha)-1, "%d/%m/%Y\t%H:%M hrs\t", t);


    fichero = fopen("log.txt", "r");
    numero=fgetc(fichero);
    
    if (numero=='\0'){
        numero='1';
    }
    
    else{
        switch(numero){
            case '1':
                numero='2';
                break;
            case '2':
                numero='3';
                break;
            case '3':
                numero='4';
                break;
            case '4':
                numero='5';
                break;
            case '5':
                numero='6';
                break;
            case '6':
                numero='7';
                break;
            case '7':
                numero='8';
                break;
            case '8':
                numero='1';
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR");
        }
    }
    fclose(fichero);
    
    fichero = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    fputc(numero,fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
    fichero = fopen("fechas.txt", "a+");
    fputs(fecha, fichero);
    fputc(numero,fichero);
    fputs("\n\n\n",fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema está en que la primera ejecución siempre crea un log.txt vacío que lleva automáticamente al default del `switch`, la segunda ejecución funciona bien escribiendo '1' en log.txt, y a partir de la tercera ejecución solo se sobreescribe por símbolos extraños y llevando al default nuevamente.

Si mi procedimiento es un fracaso total o existe un método más sencillo, agradecería me lo hicieran saber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código está bastante bien, solo te faltaron considerar algunas cosas.
Primero verificar si el txt existe `if(fichero = fopen(nombre, "r") != NULL)`. Si es así, entonces recorrer todo el archivo hasta la última linea. Si la linea no es un salto de línea sin texto entonces se acumula en la variable cant_lineas. Si no existe el archivo, se creará en el código siguiente con los valores predeterminados en la declaración de variables.

Ahora es solo cuestión de hacer el cálculo de `(cant_lineas % 8) + 1` para saber el numero de línea correspondiente.

`sprintf()` convertirá el `int` en `str` con un espaciado al inicio y luego será concatenado por `strcat()` con la fecha

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fichero;
    char line[100]={0,}, num_linea[4];
    char fecha[30]={'\0'}, nombre[]="fechas.txt";
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    strftime(fecha, sizeof(fecha)-1, "%d/%m/%Y\t%H:%M hrs", t);
    int cant_lineas=0;
    
    if((fichero = fopen(nombre, "r")) != NULL) {
        while(fgets(line, 100, fichero) != NULL) { 
            if(strcmp(line, "\n") != 0) {
                cant_lineas += 1;
            }
        }
        fclose(fichero);
    }
    
    sprintf(num_linea, "  %d", (cant_lineas % 8)+1);
    strcat(fecha, num_linea);
    fichero = fopen(nombre, "a+");
    if(cant_lineas > 0) {
        fputs("\n\n\n", fichero);
    }
    fputs(fecha, fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buenísimo, no sabía cómo plantear exactamente el contador de líneas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, voy a dar una respuesta que espero suponga un aporte diferente a la forma en que atacar el problema.

Mi respuesta se basa en 2 aspectos:

1. No veo necesario usar un archivo *auxiliar* para almacenar el número de linea.
2. Se puede hacer lento contar lineas de un archivo de *log*, cuando el mismo ha crecido en tamaño.

**CONTANDO LINEAS**

Para la primera parte, vamos a contar lineas y con ello determinaremos el número de *log* que corresponde a la linea que se va a añadir en el archivo. De esta forma evitamos crear un archivo / fichero, que tenga el número de la linea a incluir en *log*. Esto, tiene la siguiente motivación:

- Si por alguna razón el archivo auxiliar es borrado, perderemos la secuencia.
- Si por alguna razón el archivo auxiliar es sobre escrito, perderemos la secuencia.

Entonces, podemos determinar el valor del número de línea contando las lineas actuales del fichero de *log* y añadiendo el valor estimado de acuerdo a la necesidad.

Para contar el número de líneas debemos contar el número de saltos de línea en nuestro archivo. Aquí disponemos de 2 opciones:

- Usar la antigua pero fiable función [`getc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), y contar la cantidad de apariciones del carácter de fin de linea (`\n`).
- Usar la nueva y moderna función [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) (Sólo disponible en sistemas [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), como Linux o Unix) y disfrutar el uso de punteros, mientras contamos la cantidad de lineas del archivo.

**Usando `getc()`:**

```
size_t line = 0;
char buf;
buf = getc(file);
while (buf != EOF) 
{
    if(buf == '\n')
    {
        line = line + 1;
    }
    buf = getc(file);
}
```

Como se observa he declarado una variable llamada `line` de tipo [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t), para almacenar el número de líneas encontradas en el archivo. Sabemos que el número de líneas nunca será negativo y este tipo de variable me permitirá almacenar una buena magnitud de número de líneas sin temor a quedarnos cortos. Por cada carácter de fin de linea encontrado, se actualiza el contador.

Antes de continuar, vamos a ver un punto muy importante: el tamaño en caracteres de cada linea se puede establecer como un valor fijo.

En tu pregunta tienes que la salida esperada para cada linea con información es:

```
09/07/2020    23:46 hrs    1
```

Donde la fecha está separada de la hora por un carácter de tabulación ('\t') y podríamos separar el número de linea del resto de la información también con un carácter de tabulación.

Siendo así, el tamaño de cada línea es fijo:

- 21 caracteres para la información de fecha y hora (incluye tabulado final)
- 1 carácter para el número de línea (no habrán números de línea de 2 dígitos)
- 1 carácter de fin de línea.

De esta forma podemos reservar espacio por cada linea que vamos a escribir y además reservamos el espacio exacto al momento de contar las líneas.

**Usando `getline()`:**

```
static const int log_len = 21; // tamaño en caracteres de la información
static const int num_line_length = 1; // tamaño en caracteres del número de linea
size_t max_len = log_len + num_line_length + 1; // incluye el carácter de fin de línea
char *buf; // puntero que almacenará una linea
buf = (char *)malloc(max_len * sizeof(char)); // se asignan los 23 caracteres de espacio a la dirección de memoria a la que apunta buf
size_t lines = 0;

while (getline(&buf, &max_len, file) != EOF) { // file es el puntero al archivo
    lines = lines + 1;
}
```

Como se observa en el código, estamos contando la cantidad de líneas del archivo dentro del bucle `while`. El mismo se interrumpirá sólo cuando se alcance el final de dicho archivo (`EOF`).

> Como se mencionó anteriormente, `getline()` sólo está disponible en el estándar POSIX, por lo tanto no podemos usar este método en sistemas **no** POSIX (por ejemplo en [MS Windows](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)). Sin embargo, podemos usar una [alternativa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735126/are-there-alternate-implementations-of-gnu-getline-interface/735472#735472) que podemos implementar en este ambiente.

Ahora que ya tenemos la forma de contar lineas, es fácil escribir el número de linea correspondiente a la nueva entrada en nuestro archivo de *logs*. Para ello sólo debemos sumar una unidad al valor y realizar la aritmética adecuada para devolver un valor entre 1 y 8.

Haremos uso de la función [`sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) para almacenar el carácter correspondiente al número de linea que corresponde con el que se almacenará. Usaremos además, operaciones de división y resto, para calcular el número exacto a guardar:

```
sprintf(num_line, "%ld", ((lines / 3) % 8) + 1);
```

En este caso primero dividimos el número de líneas entre 3 (ya que así guardas los valores en tu archivo, cada 3 líneas). Luego calculamos el resto de dividir el número de líneas encontrado entre 8 (ya que sólo almacenaremos líneas del 1 al 8). Al resultado del resto le sumamos 1, ya que el resto de cualquier número dividido 8 es un valor en el rango del 0 al 7.

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de realizar la tarea contando las lineas ya presentes en el archivo de *logs* y añadiendo el número correspondiente.

El código puede verse de la siguiente forma:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    static const int log_len = 21;
    static const int num_line_length = 1;
    int max_len = log_len + num_line_length + 1; // incluye el carácter de fin de línea
    char log_line[max_len], num_line[num_line_length], buf, name[]="fechas.txt";
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    size_t lines = 0;

    file = fopen(name, "a+");
    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    buf = getc(file);
    while (buf != EOF) {
        if(buf == '\n') {
            lines = lines + 1;
        }
        buf = getc(file);
    }
    sprintf(num_line, "%ld", ((lines / 3) % 8) + 1);
    strftime(log_line, max_len - 1, "%d/%m/%Y\t%H:%M hrs\t", t);
    strcat(log_line, num_line);
    strcat(log_line, "\n");
    // log_line contiene los 23 caracteres, lo escribimos al archivo
    fputs(log_line, file);
    // añadimos 2 líneas adicionales al archivo
    fputs("\n\n", file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

**SIN CONTAR LINEAS**

El proceso anterior nos sirvió para mostrar que podemos contar el número de líneas de nuestro archivo y escribir el adecuado en la siguiente ejecución de nuestro programa.

Sin embargo, a medida que nuestro archivo de *logs* va creciendo en tamaño, contar lineas puede resultar lento. Imaginemos que nuestro archivo contiene 30 mil entradas válidas, eso quiere decir que tiene el triple de lineas (90 mil lineas). Si usamos el algoritmo que aplica `getc()` debemos leer carácter por carácter todos los caracteres de las 90 mil líneas para encontrar el valor del siguiente número de línea. No suena nada alentador, y a medida que el archivo crece en tamaño, se hará más pesado hacer la tarea.

Entonces, ¿cómo podemos obtener el valor de la línea correspondiente sin necesidad de contar las 90 mil líneas?

Usaremos una función llamada [`fseek()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek), para posicionar el cursor del *stream* en un lugar específico del archivo. En este caso nos interesa mover el cursor al final del archivo, por lo cual usaremos la Macro [`SEEK_END`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io#Macros).

Lo que intentaremos es leer exactamente *n* cantidad de `bytes` desde el final del archivo. Tomando en cuenta que una linea de información contiene 23 caracteres y es seguida por 2 caracteres adicionales de fin de linea, entonces el valor de *n* será 25.

Ya tenemos una variable que almacena el valor 23 (`max_len`), por lo cual vamos a sumarle simplemente 2. Además, como deseamos posicionarnos 25 caracteres por antes del final del archivo, debemos pasar el argumento como número negativo a la función `fseek()`:

```
fseek(file, -(max_len + 2), SEEK_END);
```

Con esto hemos posicionado el cursor justo al inicio de la última linea con información.

Ahora, es sencillo leer el valor del último carácter de esa línea (distinto del carácter de fin de linea). Para ello podemos apoyarnos en la función [`fread()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Y como conocemos de antemano el valor del tamaño de la línea, pues escribimos directamente lo siguiente:

```
fread(last_line, max_len, 1, file);
```

Este comando indica que volcaremos sobre `last_line` la información leída del *stream* `file`, cuyo tamaño es `max_len`, y leeremos exactamente 1 objeto de dicho tamaño.

La pregunta planteada aquí es, si el archivo aún no ha sido creado, ¿qué estoy leyendo?

Y es precisamente esta pregunta la que me permitirá resolver el problema encontrado al correr el programa por primera vez.

Si calculamos el tamaño de los datos leídos por `fread()` nos encontraremos que cuando el archivo aún no existe (no tiene datos), el tamaño del `buffer` almacenado en `last_line` es cero (0).

En cambio si hemos accedido a un archivo que ya contiene datos, el tamaño de los datos leídos será exactamente `max_len`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta podemos escribir un algoritmo que nos permita leer siempre la última linea del archivo y podremos extraer el valor del número de línea en el mismo.

Primero debemos calcular el tamaño del `buffer` leido:

```
size_t last_line_len = strlen(last_line);
```

Luego, debido a que vamos a almacenar valores que no superarán la cifra 8, podemos cambiar el tipo de dato para el valor de línea. Recordemos que ya no vamos a contar lineas, simplemente vamos a obtener el último valor almacenado en el archivo, por eso, haremos lo siguiente:

```
u_char line_number = 0; // solo valores positivos y su tamaño máximo será de 255 (empezando en cero)
```

Ahora podemos obtener el valor simplemente accediendo a la posición 21, que corresponde con el valor almacenado, pero sólo lo haremos si el tamaño del `buffer` leído es igual a `max_len`.

```
if(last_line_len == max_len) {
    line_number = last_line[21] - 48;
}
```

Como se observa, le he restado 48 al valor devuelto por `last_line`. Esto es porque el valor almacenado en una variable tipo `char` es un entero en el rango -128 a 127. Compaginando esto con la [tabla ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), los valores enteros en base decimal se corresponden con un carácter de dicha tabla. Los caracteres para dígitos numéricos empiezan en el valor decimal 48 y llegan hasta el valor decimal 57. Por lo tanto, `last_line[21]` me devolverá el valor decimal de la representación del dígito en esa posición. Al restarle el valor 48, estaré obteniendo el valor numérico (del 0 al 9) que representa dicho carácter.

Ahora que ya tengo el valor numérico de la última linea de mi archivo de *logs* aplicamos la aritmética adecuada para calcular el valor de la siguiente linea a ser añadida a nuestro archivo:

```
sprintf(num_line, "%d", (line_number % 8) + 1);
```

Hemos de aclarar que el formato usado es `"%d"` ya que me interesa el valor decimal de la operación realizada y no su representación en la tabla ASCII (la cual se obtiene usando `"%c"`).

Con esto, ya tenemos otra forma de obtener el resultado esperado, sin contar lineas, y sin usar un archivo auxiliar.

El código final puede verse así:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    static const int log_len = 21;
    static const int num_line_len = 1;
    int max_len = log_len + num_line_len + 1; // incluye el carácter de fin de línea
    char log_line[max_len], last_line[max_len], name[]="fechas.txt", num_line[num_line_len];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    u_char line_number = 0;
    
    file = fopen(name, "a+");
    
    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    fseek(file, -(max_len + 2), SEEK_END);
    
    fread(last_line, max_len, 1, file);
    
    size_t last_line_len = strlen(last_line);

    if(last_line_len == max_len) {
        line_number = last_line[21] - 48;
    }
    
    sprintf(num_line, "%d", (line_number % 8) + 1);
    
    strftime(log_line, max_len - 1, "%d/%m/%Y\t%H:%M hrs\t", t);
    strcat(log_line, num_line);
    strcat(log_line, "\n");
    fputs(log_line, file);
    fputs("\n\n", file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```